# IJavaScriptExecutor return null

Tags: c#, jquery, selenium

I'm trying to get element in jquery but I get a `null` value of the returned object.

Code shown below:

```
public IWebElement Executescript(IWebDriver driver, String script)
{
   return (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script);
}

public IWebElement getuserpasserror()
{
   IWebElement error = op.Executescript(this.driver, "$('li').html()");   
   return error;
}
```

But the returned value `error` is `null`.

Comment: what is `IWebElement` and `IJavaScriptExecutor`.

Comment: fyi jquery does not return an element with `.html()`

Comment: IwebElement it is selenium webdriver element.

Comment: I used $(li).html cause I want the text in <li>....</li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues.

1. You appear to be under the illusion that you **need** to use jQuery. This is incorrect and I have seen very few (countable using my fingers on a single hand) on when jQuery or rather, JavaScript, is absolutely required to find an element in Selenium.
2. Your current method is casting the result of `ExecuteScript` into an `IWebElement`. This is incorrect because you are returning a `string` (`.html()` returns a `string`)
3. You appear to be using jQuery for little use anyway, [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) merely calls `.innerHTML` with a few things to cater for older browsers. **You can do this in Selenium anyway!**:

> This method uses the browser's innerHTML property. Some browsers may not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original document. For example, Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric characters.

1. Selenium's JavaScript executor will need a little pushing and poking to give it a *hint* that the JavaScript you are passing to it is going to *return* something.
2. Since you are bound to using jQuery, your solution is going to break on a page that doesn't have jQuery loaded.

So, what I'd do is the following:

1. Since your method is doing nothing useful (you've restricted yourself to `IWebElement`'s being returned by your JS), then I would simply call it directly:

   `string error = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return $('li').html()").ToString();`
2. Since you don't *absolutely require* jQuery to find your elements, why are you not finding them using Selenium *first*? You appear to be working **against** the API given to you. There are various ways to find elements.

   `driver.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));`
3. To completely remove the jQuery dependency here, to replicate *mostly* what the `html()` property does, simply call `GetAttribute` and look for `innerHTML`:

   `element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");`
4. Further, why the need for this `innerHTML`/`.html()` *at all*? Why does `.Text` not return what you expect?
5. Finally, to put this altogether, using LINQ:

   `IEnumerable<string> html = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("li")).Select(i => i.GetAttribute("innerHTML"));`

This is an exact replication of what you are attempting to do using jQuery, but without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium, you do not need to use jQuery to find elements. You can use built in Selenium functions.

```
var text = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("li")).Text;
```

If you must you jQuery the issue may be that you are not returning anything in your script. It should be something like this:

```
var error = op.Executescript(this.driver, "return $('li').html();");
```

Comment: Thanks I know but there is places that I need to use jquery(Instead xpath)'so I want to learn how to do it

Comment: In that case, your script is not returning anything because you do not have a return in it. You could try this: op.Executescript(this.driver, "return $('li').html();");

Comment: This isn't *totally* the correct answer, but the problem is in two parts: 1) you must tell Selenium's JavaScript Executor to "return" something from a piece of JS you are giving it, otherwise it'll not give you anything and 2) That jQuery isn't going to result in an `IWebElement`, it'll return a `string`. FWIW, the `html()` jQuery method does nothing other than call `.innerHTML` (which you can do without executing JS) and a few things to cater for older browsers. You are gaining **absolutely nothing** by using jQuery here.